# Putting data from an Array into a 2D array Java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

Lets say I have an array of strings as followed

```
[red,black,blue,orange,green]
```

What I want to do is put this in a 2D array as so:

```
[red][black][blue][orange][green]
[red][black][blue][orange][green]
[red][black][blue][orange][green]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What error did you get when you ran your attempt? Please show your code, the result and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String [] anArray1 = {red, black, blue, orange, green};
String [][] anArray2 = new String[3][5];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   for(int q = 0; q < 5; q++)
   {
     anArray2[i][q] = anArray1[q];
   }
}
```

I did not actually test this so if you copy/ paste it it not might work, but the idea behind the code is there.